# CakePHP inputDefaults and rewrite by field

Tags: cakephp, form-helpers

I've created a large form in Cake and set default options via `inputDefaults`. However I wish to change the default values for an individual field.

In setting the form defaults, I wrote approximately this:

```
'inputDefaults' => array(
    'error' => array(
        'attributes' => array(
            'wrap' => 'span',
            'class' => 'invalidate column-7 offset-3')));
```

...with the result that all like fields produce the same error message. But, when I attempt to change the defaults for a single field, like so:

```
echo $this->Form->input('name', array(
    'error' => array(
        'attributes' => array(
            'wrap' => 'span',
            'class' => 'invalidate column-10'))));
```

It doesn't work. The field `name` produces an error whose class reads `column-7` and `offset-3`, whereas I'd intended `column-10`.

Anybody know a solution?

Comment: Ok, tried the exact same code you provided, and it worked, I get the individual class for one input. Also checked the API of the formhelper and all is in order. Maybe if you provide the version of cake, it would help, but at least 2.x works. You haven't changed the FormHelper? And are you sure the error class is not `column-10`? maybe the div of the input is messing the layout instead of the error class. Cleared the cache of the browser?

Comment: where did you set your inputDefaults? at the time of loading the FormHelper in controller or when creating the form?

Answer (score 0):

$options['inputDefaults'] You can declare a set of default options for input() with the inputDefaults key to customize your default input creation:

```
echo $this->Form->create('User', array(
    'inputDefaults' => array(
        'label' => false,
        'div' => false
    )
));
```

All inputs created from that point forward would inherit the options declared in inputDefaults. You can override the defaultOptions by declaring the option in the input() call:

```
echo $this->Form->input('password'); // No div, no label
// has a label element
echo $this->Form->input(
    'username',
    array('label' => 'Username')
);
```